# Считывает массив символов только до точки С++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Условия задачи: перевести массив символов (для примера $123,456,789,12) в вещественное число. Функция должна игнорировать все символы в массиве кроме цифр и точки, заливать их в новый массив и уже из него перевести в вещественное число.

Проблема: нет цифр после точки. Т.е. результат будет из вышепредложенного примера 123456789,00.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
//////////////////////////////////////////
const int MAX = 100;  //максимальное количество символов массива
//////////////////////////////////////////
long double mstold(char mon[MAX]); // прототип ф-ции перевода массива в 
                                   // вещественное число
//////////////////////////////////////////
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    char money[MAX], ch; //массив и переменная для повтора
    long double newmoney; //вещественное число/результат
    do                     //основной цикл
    {
        cout << "Введите денежную сумму: ";
        //cin.get(money, MAX, '\n'); в таком виде, при попытке повторного ввода 
        //                           программа сходит с ума, но это не решает
        //                           проблемы 
        cin >> setw(MAX) >> money; // ввод массива символов
        int l = strlen(money);      // если поместить проверку массива на
        for (int p = 0; p < l; p++) // введенные символы, то видно что уже при
        {                           // вводе отсутствуют символы после точки
            cout << money[p];       //
        }                           //
        newmoney = mstold(money);  // вызов ф-ции и присвоение результата
        cout << "Вы ввели: " << setiosflags(ios::fixed) << setiosflags(ios::showpoint) << setprecision(2) << newmoney << endl << endl; 
        //вывод результата
        do                         // цикл повторного ввода
        {
            cout << "повторить(y/n)? ";
            cin >> ch;
            if (ch != 'n' && ch != 'y')
            {
                cout << "Неверный ввод!!" << endl;
            }
        } while (ch != 'n' && ch != 'y');
        cout << endl << endl;
    } while (ch != 'n');

}
//////////////////////////////////////////
long double mstold(char mon[MAX]) // ф-ция перевода
{
    int k = strlen(mon); // определение длины массива
    int j = 0;           // счетчик нового массива
    long double n;       // вещественное переменная для перевода
    char chr[MAX];       // новый массив
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) //цикл отсева ненужных символов в новый массив
    {
        if (mon[i] - 48 >= 0 && mon[i] - 48 <= 9 || mon[i]=='.')
        {
            chr[j] = mon[i];
            j++;
        }
        chr[j] = '\0'; // установка конца нового массива
    }
    n = atof(chr); // ф-ция преобразования массива в вещественное число
    return n; // возврат результата
}
```

Подскажите как можно решить эту проблему??....

Comment: `setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");` заставляет считать, что десятичная дробь идет не после точки, а после запятой - в `atof`, а вы ей подсовываете точку...

Comment: СПАСИБО ПОМОГЛО!!!!! А как теперь заставить компилятор понимать русский и при этом чтобы все работало и желательно без костылей?

Comment: ну так добавьте перед `chr[j] = mon[i];` такое- `if (mon[i] == ',') { mon[i] = '.';}` и все (ну или наоборот). Хотя я бы убрал `setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");`  и не будет никаких проблем.